# Entity Framework Fluent API One-Zero-or-One Relationship Configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship, fluent

I have the following 2 classes. An Item can exist without the need for an 'ExportSiteLog' to be assigned to it, but an instance of 'ExportSiteLog' must relate to a single instance of 'item':

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ExportSiteLog Log { get; set; }
}

public class ExportSiteLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Fluent API for my entity model configuration and haven't yet been able to figure out the correct configuration for these 2 objects. I am using a separate class for each EntityTypeConfiguration, e.g:

```
public class ItemConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
    {
        public ItemConfig()
        {
            HasOptional(item => item.Log)
                .WithRequired(export => export.Item);

            ToTable("Items");
        }
    }
```

...and tried something like this on the ExportSiteLog configuration:

```
HasRequired(export => export.Item)
    .WithOptional(item => item.Log);
```

I was originally getting an EF error when running (code-first) update-database, saying:

> "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'xxx.ExportSiteLog' and 'xxx.Item'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations."

Implementing the above EntityTypeConfigurations, this error seemed to disappear when I run 'update-database', but my 2 tables in the DB do not seem to have added a FK 'Id' column in either tables, which I would expect to see.

Comment: Typo? `item.ExportSiteLog` should be `item.Log`.

Comment: Ooops. Thanks. Corrected.